# How to pass in the initial state of the component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component and I want to test it with React Testing Library. The component has an initial state but I want to override it for my tests and provide a custom initial state so I can test various things. How to I do that in Jest?

```
function App() {
    const initialState = [
        {
            id: uuidv4(),
            date: new Date(),
            desc: "initial",
            amount: 0,
            type: "travel",
        },
    ];
    const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(initialState);

    return (
        <div className={Styles.app}>
            <h1 className="p-4">Expense tracker</h1>
            <Container>
                <AddExpense setExpenses={setExpenses} expenses={expenses} />
                <FilterExpense expenses={expenses} setExpenses={setExpenses} />
                <ListExpense setExpenses={setExpenses} expenses={expenses} />
                <BreakdownExpense expenses={expenses} />
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
test("custom initial state", () => {
    const initialState = [
        {
            id: 1,
            date: new Date(),
            desc: "test 1",
            amount: 0,
            type: "10",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            date: new Date(),
            desc: "test 2",
            amount: 0,
            type: "20",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            date: new Date(),
            desc: "test 3",
            amount: 0,
            type: "30",
        },
    ];
    const [expenses, setExpenses] = React.useState(initialState);
    render(<App expenses={expenses} />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/test 1/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/test 2/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

--- Update
I have a fix for it but I don't like the implementation. I'm putting testing data and logic in the component but I should be keeping them separate.

App comp:

```
function App({ testApp }) {
const testInitialState = [
    {
        id: 1,
        date: new Date(),
        desc: "test 1",
        amount: 0,
        type: "10",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        date: new Date(),
        desc: "test 2",
        amount: 0,
        type: "20",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        date: new Date(),
        desc: "test 3",
        amount: 0,
        type: "30",
    },
];

const initialState = [
    {
        id: uuidv4(),
        date: new Date(),
        desc: "initial",
        amount: 0,
        type: "initial",
    },
];

const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(
    testApp ? testInitialState : initialState
);

return (......
```

test.js:

```
test(("filter expenses buttons", () => {
    render(<App testApp={true} />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/test 1/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/test 2/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: The way your component is structured, you can't. Interact with the rendered components _as the user would_ to get to the current state

Comment: Either that, or make the initial state a property if it's intended to be supplied by the caller

Comment: Yeah, I created the state in the component for testing and added a switch to it. But there must be a way for me to do it in jest.

Comment: I dont think you can do it,
this is the only way I know because you cant access the initial value you need to pass it the initial value
or use useffect and change base on. value but this is the same stuff without the extra rerender

Comment: Mock `useState` and have it return whatever you want.

Comment: Why not pass the initialState as a prop to the App component?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Yeah I have done that now but still have the logic in the component to switch out the normal initial state to the test initial state.